# Changing behaviour of certain anchor tags, even when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In a web project, there is a need for opening some links in some kind of overlay window, while others should open just normally.

The links always come as normal anchor tags and can …

- be added as fixed content in templates
- be added by moderators using a html editor, such as tinyMCE

I was spending a fair amount of time considering what would be a safe, proper, fairly crossbrowser-compatible and elegant mechanism. My final idea was to use a class on the `a`-tags called `overlayWindow` and simply force moderators to add this class to the links if they create links they want to be opened within the overlay window.

All this is fine. Now i can just do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.overlayWindow').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // set off an ajax request to get overlay window content, then display it
    });
});
```

Great. But there is a problem. The anchor tags can also

- be provided dynamically, even added to the page after page load

Which means that i need some safe way to make sure that the above code is executed whenever any further anchor tags are added to the page (by whatever means).

Since this seems rather far out, i could also live with a solution that kind of intercepts all ajax requests and makes sure the preparation code is executed whenever an ajax call has finished.

Can this be done? If yes, how?

(I am also fairly open to entirely different approaches to solving my actual problem, so any suggestions are welcome).

Comment: what is the problem??? if you're using .on()  the click handler will be added to all elements .  It does not matter when they were added into the DOM

Comment: Sorry, i first misread your comment. I thought that using a selector and applying certain handlers to the elements returned by it, will only affect those elements which are part of the document at that given point in time?

Comment: @Scott: that is not true. `on` only works the way you suggest with event delegation. The OPs code does not aknowledge this (it requires an additional parameter between the event-name and the callback funciton). See my answer. Also: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to achieve this is with [event delegation.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) All click events will "bubble" up through their ancestor elements in the DOM and can be intercepted as a click on any one of those ancestor elemens.

So add one more parameter in the `.on` function between the event name and the callback function  -- place the selector for the clicked element there instead. And now call jquery `$()` on a container object that listens for clicks as they bubble up to the container.

For example, if you were sure that all of these links will be placed at some level inside, say, any div with a class 'containerClassName' applied to them, and you were sure that such container-divs are always present at page-load, then:

```
$('.containerClassName').on('click', 'a.overlayWindow', function(event){ ... //etc.
```

Will ensure that all your `overlayWindow` links will get "heard" when their clicks bubble up to a `.containerClassName`,. And then the event can be handled properly, and with the callback you provide, and with `this` representing the `a.overlayWindow` link.

Comment: Thank you, i see your point, but the problem is precisely that certain such tags may not be available on page load.

Comment: I understand. You only need ot ensure that *some* element containing these tags is present at pageload, not the tags themselves. Sorry if I wasn't clear about. It's this container that you target with `containerClassName`. This could even be the `body` element (though that's generally in-advisable for performance reasons.)

Comment: Why not make an anchor styled in the way you need it to be and display:none;? Then you can use jquery to duplicate it via .clone() whenever needed, then just set display to block on the newly cloned anchors.

Comment: @Faust Oh, so you mean i could basically do this with the document body as well, and it will result in all links with class `overlayWindow` behaving the desired way, even if they are added later on, even after the page has loaded? (Gary: thank you for your input, but this seems way out of line to me - i want to keep my html structure clean, which is why i chose to use the `class`-attribute based approach in the first place)

Comment: This is a very common case with an well-understood and commonly implemented solution. I urge you to read the jqyery primer on this: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @SquareCat: yes. Absolutely.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! I'll look into it and apply the solution, right away.

Comment: Perfect solution. Exactly what i needed. Many kudos!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I had to correct my written description of the jquery pattern, though my code-sample was fine.